# Cannot Open Extensions Window in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I cannot open the Extensions window in Chrome. Whether I go through the menubar, Windows --> Extensions, or through Preferences, Preferences --> Extensions, nothing opens up.

I am using Chrome Version 52.0.2743.60 beta (64-bit), on a Mac running OSX 10.11.6

Comment: What does the page say when you hit the url chrome://extensions/  ?

Comment: I tried opening that url in a new tab. It just closed the tab and came back to this page.

Comment: Open an incognito window and then try it. What happens then?

Comment: Same thing. It just closed the window

Comment: Maybe something is corrupt. I'd try uninstalling/reinstalling next.

Comment: Something must be corrupt, but deeply embedded. I've tried reinstalling, and clearing all of my data. The problem is still persisting.

Comment: Be sure to delete user>library>application support>google>chrome

Comment: I tried that, as well. There was nothing there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always encounter this. Try navigating to Chrome's extension folder on Mac (~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions) and see if there is an extension there you do not recognize. Google the extension ID and see what its name is. Once you do that, if it seems to be malware or adware, delete it. Personally, I believe malware on Macs is an issue that is encountered far too often, yet is disregarded as a problem. Hope this helps!

Comment: yes it helps, thank you. unfortunately there are some malware plugins that does not allow to open the extensions tab

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this was due to a common malware program. I got rid of it by following the instructions here: http://www.thesafemac.com/arg/

**EDIT** This only solved the problem for a few hours. Then the ads came back, along with being prevented from opening Extensions.